How to Customize Bold ReportViewer Toolbar to Show Only Print and Refresh Buttons in Angular
I'm using the Angular Bold ReportViewer component, which displays all the toolbar options by default. I would like to customize the toolbar to display only the "Print" and "Refresh" buttons. How can I achieve this configuration?
Here is my initial code angular component and html code
import { Component, Inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog, MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { MatSnackBar, MatSnackBarConfig } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ReportviewerService } from './reportviewer.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'reports-reportviewer-dialog',
  templateUrl: './reports-reportviewer-dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: [],
  providers: []
})

export class ReportsReportviewerDialogComponent implements OnInit {
  public serviceUrl: string;
  public reportPath: string;
  public parameters: any;
  constructor(
    private ReportviewerService: ReportviewerService,
     @Inject('BASE_URL') private _baseUrl: string,
      private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.serviceUrl = _baseUrl + 'api/PMISReports'
    this.reportPath = this.ReportviewerService.ReportName;
    this.parameters = this.ReportviewerService.Parameters;
  }
  onAjaxRequest(event) {
    if (sessionStorage.getItem('PMIS_currentUser').length > 0) {
      var token = sessionStorage.getItem('PMIS_currentUser')
      event.headers.push({ Key: 'Authorization', Value: 'Bearer ' + token });
      //  event.headers.push({ Key: 'ReportID', Value: uuid.v4() });
      }

  }
  ngOnInit() {

  }


Here is what I have done but still not getting the desired output
import { Component, Inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog, MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { MatSnackBar, MatSnackBarConfig } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ReportviewerService } from './reportviewer.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'reports-reportviewer-dialog',
  templateUrl: './reports-reportviewer-dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: [],
  providers: []
})

export class ReportsReportviewerDialogComponent implements OnInit {
  public serviceUrl: string;
  public reportPath: string;
  public parameters: any;
  public toolbarSettings: any ;
  public exportSettings: any;
  public isPrintMode: boolean;
  constructor(
    private ReportviewerService: ReportviewerService,
     @Inject('BASE_URL') private _baseUrl: string,
      private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.serviceUrl = _baseUrl + 'api/PMISReports'
    this.reportPath = this.ReportviewerService.ReportName;
    this.parameters = this.ReportviewerService.Parameters;
    this.isPrintMode = true;
    this.toolbarSettings = {
      items: ['Print', 'Refresh']
  };
  this.exportSettings = {
      exportOptions: ['Pdf'] // Limit export options to only PDF
  };
  

  }
  onAjaxRequest(event) {
    if (sessionStorage.getItem('PMIS_currentUser').length > 0) {
      var token = sessionStorage.getItem('PMIS_currentUser')
      event.headers.push({ Key: 'Authorization', Value: 'Bearer ' + token });
      //  event.headers.push({ Key: 'ReportID', Value: uuid.v4() });
      }

  }
  ngOnInit() {

  }




}

HTML

<div class="p-2">
    <bold-reportviewer id="dashboard"   [parameters] = "parameters" (ajaxBeforeLoad)="onAjaxRequest($event)" [reportServiceUrl]="serviceUrl" [reportPath]="reportPath" style="width: 100%;height: 500px">
    </bold-reportviewer>
</div>



